Some maximal inequality of Fefferman-Stein type
Let $1 < p < \infty$. Fefferman-Stein shows that
there exists a constant $c_p > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (M[f](x))^p \phi(x) \,dx \leq c_p \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (f(x))^p M[\phi](x) \,dx
\end{equation}
for all non-negative measurable functions $f$ and $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$
where $M$ denote the usual Hardy-Littlewood maximal operator.
To Generalize this inequality, let $0 < r < \infty$ and for non-negative function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, define
\begin{equation}
  M^{(r)}[f](x)
    := ( M[f^r](x))^{1/r}.
\end{equation}
If $r = 1$, then $M^{(r)} = M$.
Can we conclude that for any $1 < p < \infty$, there exists a constant $c_p > 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (M[f]^{(r)}(x))^p \phi(x) \,dx \leq c_p \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (f(x))^p M^{(r)}[\phi](x) \,dx
\end{equation}
for all non-negative measurable functions $f$ and $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$?
